# Basic confusion with classes & modules (Specially with "self")

Tags: python, class, oop

I thought that this code would work

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        B = self.create_b()
        print(B.y)

    def create_b(self):
        class B:
            def __init__(self):
                self.y = self.x
        return B
A = A()
```

but I receive the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'y'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing classes with class *instances* (not Python modules). In Python `class` statements are executable and create a callable object that you must then be called to create **instance** objects of the class that was defined.

Regular methods of a class automatically receive a first argument that's the instance they belong to, and by convention, this argument is usually called `self`.

Here's what I mean:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        B = self.create_b()  # Create B class.
        b = B(self)  # Create instance of B class passing this instance of A.
        print(b.y)

    def create_b(self):
        class B:
            def __init__(self, a_inst):
                self.y = a_inst.x
        return B

a = A()  # -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with this code. The first is that since `create-b` returns a class object, not an instance of the class, B's `__init__` was never run. You could solve this with

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        B = self.create_b()
        b = B()
        print(b.y)

    def create_b(self):
        class B:
            def __init__(self):
                self.y = self.x
        return B
A = A()
```

The second is that nested classes do not have access to the wrapping method's local namespace like a nested function (closure) would. When attempting `self.y = self.x`, instances of class B have no special relationship with the instance of A that created them. You could solve this with

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        B = self.create_b(self)
        b = B()
        print(b.y)

    def create_b(self):
        class B:
            def __init__(self, a):
                self.y = a.x
        return B
A = A()
```

The third is that python creates a `weakref` to classes when they are defined that never goes away. Each time you call `create_b`, you create a small memory leak. You could solve this with

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        b = B(self)
        print(b.y)

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.y = a.x
A = A()
```

Comment: The whole point of a weak reference is that it isn't sufficient, by itself, to prevent an object from being garbage collected. Do you have a reference for your claim of a memory leak?

Comment: The second block of code throws an error in line:  ```B = self.create_b(self)```, it can be solved by changing that line and the following one to ```B = self.create_b(),   b = B(self)```